# Show Login View Controller on Certain Pages of Tab Bar Application Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application with three views. One of these requires the user to login to view the content.

I would like to initially show a login view when the user selects that tab and then after they are authenticated have them skip the login view and go directly to their content.

I've seen on other questions to check for authentication state in the ViewControllers `viewWillAppear` method and if not authenticated to present the login screen via a modal. However doing this hides the tab bar when showing the login view.

What would be the correct way to set this up?

Comment: How are you showing the login form? Presenting it or pushing it? If you present it, it will go over the tab bar. But pushing it on to the UINavigationController will still leave it visible.

Comment: Currently I am presenting it with a modal presentation style of `.overContext`


`let loginViewController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login")) as! LoginViewController

loginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

present(loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)`